# Which way of including content multiple times into one layout in Docpad is most appropriate?

Tags: docpad

I've started to digging into the Docpad for my current project and so far I've discovered 3 ways to include content.

- We use **content** template data variable to include child layout/document into the layout.
- We have **include(relativePath)** method to include the content of another file at the given path.
- Finally we have **partials** plugin which provides the way to insert documents into other documents, and also be passed by the docpad rendering engine.

We can use **content** variable only once per document. But often we have multiple places within static template where we need to include content. So why we ever need to use **content** variable if we always can use, say, **include**, or **partials** (when installed) which does not have this limit of only single usage per document? I guess that there are own pros, cons and use cases for each way of including content. So I'm wondering which way is most appropriate and in what case, assuming that we want to include content multiple times in one layout?

Comment: It depends on what it is you want to include several times. What is it that you want to include several times?

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think I know what you are trying to do. There may be various places on the page where you might want to have content. The standard way would be to use partials in each of the places where you want content. Also, remember that you can also call partials from within a partial. This is an example of a page I have for my blog:

```
 <% for doc in @getCollection('posts').toJSON(): %>
       <%- @partial('content/post.html.eco',{document:doc,showComments:false}) %>
<div class="hr clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
 <% end %>
```

In the partial I have:

```
 <article class="panel">

    <header>
        <h3 class="title"><a href="<%= @document.url.replace(/\\/g, '/') %>"><%=@document.title%></a><time datetime="<%=@document.date.toISOString()%>" class="postdate"><%=@document.date.toDateString()%></time></h3>
    </header>

    <!-- Post Data -->
    <p class="sub"><strong class="tag_bg"></strong>
    <%for tag in @document.tags: %>
        <a class="catlink" href="/"><%=tag%></a> 
    <%end%>
    <a class="commentlink" href="#">0</a>
    </p>

    <% if (@document.image):%>
    <figure>

        <a class="islink_m" href="#" data-rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]" title="<%=@document.title%>"></a>
        <span class="image-holder-medium">
            <img class="thumb" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" alt="" src="<%=@document.image%>"></span>

    </figure>
    <%end%>

    <p><%-@document.content%></p>

    <footer>
        <%if(@showComments):%>
    <%- @partial('content/social.html') %>
    <%- @partial('content/disqus.html.eco', {site:@site,document: @document}) %>
        <%end%>
    </footer>

</article>
```